# why php-slim api route is not throwing any error despite email is not being sent

Tags: php, rest, phpmailer, postman, slim

Hi i'm in a situation where i'm unable to send email from `PHP-Slim`  with `PHP Mailer`.

this is the my `get` url => `http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/sendMail`

i'm not getting any kind of `error` even though my `email` is not sent.

**below** is my `postman` screen shot

[image]

**RELIEF FOR ME:** i'm able to login but failing to send `email`

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/login','login'); /* User login */
$app->get('sendMail','sendMail');  /* send Email */     


$app->run();

/************************* USER LOGIN *************************************/
/* ### User login ### */
function login() {
      // Code for login API route, it is there with slim api folder
 }


/* ### send email test ### */  

function sendMail()     
{

    // below credential is my actual mailtrap credential



    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '1fd562fc56d940';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'af5ec48a984df1';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'PLAIN';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 2525;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

}


?>
```

**below is my whole project folder with mailtrap email credentials**

(DROPBOX Link) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrl8j198nd1rfqh/PHP-Slim-Restful.zip?dl=0

please use the above `dropbox` link of my project.

**I think my API `route` is not hitting the `function` but i'm able to hit `login` route why?.**

**Even `echo "hello world"` is not displaying. i think postman is not hitting the route?why**

Comment: You should set mail server in-order to send email from localhost

Comment: my `localhost` is configured to send `email`, any how i'm just trying to send mail to my `mailtrap`.   i have done this before many times with `laravel`.

Comment: You're calling isSMTP, but are not importing the class name, nor requiring the class file, though you shouldn't need to load any manually since you're using composer.

Comment: @Synchro, please help me how to do that. Either posting in comment or as answer.

Comment: The same way you're importing the other class names into your namespace - with a `use` statement, exactly as the PHPMailer examples do.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out somethings..
add the following

```
$mailer->isSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mailer->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mailer->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```